# Where does Windows store its wallpapers?

Tags: windows-xp

I run Windows XP and the wallpaper I used to have got lost. I have backups of the system itself, so if I knew where to look, I could find a copy of the old wallpaper.

I have some idea of the original filename (searching now), and I recall it saves it as a bitmap, but an exact location would be helpful.

It was a photo/JPEG that used to be on the filesystem, and I don't have backups, so the Firefox, and Internet Explorer wallpaper locations are unlikely. I checked `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32` as well - so I'm assuming it's somewhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft`

Should be in this location.

In Windows 10 (also 8.1) the wallpaper is under this folder location:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\RoamedThemeFiles\DesktopBackground`

Comment: its not the same... and he's right. it was in G:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\wallpaper1.bmp

Answer (score 12):

It should be here, at least if it is a stock wallpaper:

> C:\WINDOWS\Web\Wallpaper

If it is custom, it is here:

> C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Internet Explorer Wallpaper.bmp

With FF 4, it saves it to:

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\username\Application
>   Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Desktop
>   Background.bmp

After you clarified that you actually wanted the location that Firefox saved it to, I noticed something: If you go to the location where the wallpaper is set, the name of it there, is the name of the actual file. So as in this screenshot,

[image]

the name is Desktop Background, so doing a `dir "desktop background.bmp" /s` would find it. I would assume this would work even if another browser saved it to yet another location, or file name.

Comment: hmm, that would be true for a wallpaper from IE. Firefox has its own location as well i believe. upvoted since.. its mostly right, but not for my case

Comment: @Journeyman Geek I suppose there may be some version that saves it to the location in the other answer, but I just did it with FF4, and it saved it to the location I added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows 10, I found mine in the registry on key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the location of any background in Windows 7:

- Go to **Personalize** (right-click on desktop)
- Select any theme
- Click **Desktop Background**
- You should see picture location path displayed

...courtesy of [James M. Fisher, windowstalk.org](http://www.windowstalk.org/2010/07/where-does-windows-7-store-background-images/).

For instance, if you set a background image in FireFox using **Set as Desktop Background** , the image is stored in:

```
\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox
```