# Where does Windows store its current wallpaper?

Tags: windows, desktop-customization

I created an image for a desktop wallpaper and set the image directly in Windows (not from a browser). However, the image file I made is no longer on my computer, but the wallpaper is still there. How can I retrieve this wallpaper? It has to load from somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Windows store its wallpapers?](http://superuser.com/questions/304801/where-does-windows-store-its-wallpapers), [How can I find the file that is currently used as a wallpaper in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/173397/how-can-i-find-the-file-that-is-currently-used-as-a-wallpaper-in-windows-7), [Custom Windows 7 wallpapers location](http://superuser.com/questions/245930/custom-windows-7-wallpapers-location), [How could I find out the path to the current desktop image, for Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/507571/how-could-i-find-out-the-pa) ...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Windows XP** ([Reference](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-xp/29316-where-does-xp-keep-current-wallpaper-2.html)):

You can find the actual path in the registry key named **Wallpaper** at
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]

Usually it's something like:

C:\Documents and Settings\ *[YOURUSERNAME]* \Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Wallpaper1.bmp

**Windows 7** ([Reference](https://superuser.com/questions/207852/where-is-the-wallpaper-folder-in-windows-7)):

C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper (default themes)

C:\Users\ *[YOURUSERNAME]* \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes ( any new themes that you might have installed )

C:\Users\ *[YOURUSERNAME]* \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes ( any other pictures that you might have made as an wallpaper.

Comment: Under Win7, it's exact location is `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg`

Comment: Is there a windows 10 option now?

Comment: @ForwardEd The current wallpaper on Windows 10 is saved as C:\Users\[YOURUSERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper

Comment: @SnoringFrog nice - I just had to add .jpg as the extension and she opened right up.

Answer (score 3):

The specifics would depend on your Windows version, but going by Windows 7 (which should be reasonably useful in the absence of a specified version, and which I have easy access to):

- right-click on the desktop and pick *Personalize*
- click *Desktop Background*
- right-click on the selected image and either:

  - pick *Properties* and look under *General*, *Location*
  - or, pick something under *Open With*

This should provide you access to the file so that you can copy or save it elsewhere. I would guess that it is stored in a temporary files folder somewhere currently.

Comment: Great! This is the easiest way on how to know the image's file path.